# Adjusting indenting for lisp if statements

Tags: indentation, common-lisp, emacs-lisp-mode, lisp

I am learning common lisp and am trying to follow the style guide suggested by [lisp-lang.org](https://lisp-lang.org/style-guide/). In this style guide is an `if` statement style that I think makes the code more readable:

```
(if (cond)
    (true-branch)
    (false-branch))
```

That is, the branches line up. I find this to be syntactically easier to read. Using `lisp-mode` with no extra goodies the default seems to be:

```
(if (cond)
    (true-branch)
  (false-branch))
```

For some strange reason. The false block is pushed back to line up with the `f` of the if statement. I find this a little jarring.

Is there a way to clean this up so I can have the default formatting conform the linked styleguide?

Comment: FWIW, I believe the reason behind this indentation style is that the 3rd, 4th, ... args are all part of the "else" (i.e. there's an implicit `progn` around the rest of the args).  The style you want is the one typically used in Scheme where the `if` traditionally does not accept more than 3 args IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why is Emacs so weird?

Emacs indents lisp code as if it were Emacs Lisp, where [`if`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html) accepts unlimited `else` forms; unlike in Common Lisp, where [`if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) accepts at most 3 arguments.

## What to do?

Tell Emacs to indent Lisp as if it were Common Lisp:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function))
(autoload 'common-lisp-indent-function "cl-indent" "Common Lisp indent.")
```